# Repeating items in dynamic drop down list

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a site which, (with php), dynamically fills a dropdown list with 'material' (column Name) I'm getting from a VIEW in my db used to query a select number of entries depending on previous parameters.  Two fields searched through this way are 'company' and 'materials'.  Each entry could potentially include the same 'material' for different companies...but the company will be different -- same goes the other way around, companies could both use an alike material so therefore there will be multiple items in that dropdown.  Problem is that when the dropdown list gets populated from this view...it repeats items on that list seeing that they are used with other companies.  Can this be prevented as I only need it to show one time for each material.  Perhaps a function is check if any duplicate or a clause in my query?  I've been looking into using DISTINCT but not really sure how to apply it.

This is my view query btw:

```
    select `bp`.`id` AS `id`,
`bp`.`brand_id` AS `brand_id`,
`bp`.`width` AS `width`,
`bp`.`height` AS `height`,
`bp`.`material` AS `material`,
`bp`.`type` AS `type`,
`bp`.`cost` AS `cost`,
`bp`.`last_updated` AS `last_updated`,
`bp`.`created` AS `created`,
`b`.`company` AS `company` 
FROM (((`caseys_wrdp4`.`windows_brands_products` `bp` 
left join `caseys_wrdp4`.`windows_brands` `b` 
on((`bp`.`brand_id` = `b`.`id`))) 
join `caseys_wrdp4`.`Windows_last_submissions` `ls`) 
join `caseys_wrdp4`.`windows_materials` `wm`) 
where ((`bp`.`width` = round(`ls`.`width`,0)) 
and (`bp`.`height` = round(`ls`.`height`,0)) 
and (`bp`.`material` = `wm`.`name`) 
and (`bp`.`type` = `ls`.`type`) 
and if((`ls`.`minimumbid` <> '0.00'),(`bp`.`cost` between `ls`.`minimumbid` and `ls`.`maximumbid`),(`bp`.`cost` <= `ls`.`maximumbid`))) 
order by `b`.`company` desc
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? See also [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Comment: If you're only populating a drop down why on earth would you return all of the fields from the view?  why not just select the KEY value and the text then distinct would work fine.  Use the Key value for the value in the drop down and the text for the display... Example `SELECT distinct material, ID from Viewname`